# vuejs 2 deployment by two users

Tags: node.js, nginx, deployment, vuejs2

I would like to deploy vuejs 2 application on vps with nginx. App has been inited with webpack template.

I've created app-dir/ with 2775 chmod. App would be deployed by 2 users. Both are assigned to www-data group. Nginx user is set to www-data. Owner and group of app-dir/ are set to www-data.

deployment script:

```
#!/bin/bash
git checkout master
git pull
npm install
npm run build
```

It works only for one user. When 2nd user run the script, receives error:

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '(...)/dist/static/css'

The error occurs because directories created by npm run build have 2755 chmode instead of 2775.

How should we deploy this app?